# Converting disrete chunks of Stdin to usable form

Tags: scala, iterator, stdin

Simply, if the user pastes a chunk of text (multiple lines) into the console all at once, I want to be able to grab that chunk and use it.

Currently my code is

```
val stringLines: List[String] = io.Source.stdin.getLines().toList
doStuff(stringLines)
```

However doStuff is never called. I realize the stdin iterator doesn't have an 'end', but how do I get the input as it is currently? I've checked many SO answers, but none of them work for multiple lines that need to be collated. I need to have all the lines of the user input at once, and it will always come as a single paste of data.

Comment: How can you tell the difference between two lines that were typed in, slowly, and two lines that were pasted in as a chunk?  If you timestamped each one you could decide that time difference < threshold is a chunk.  Is there another way to discern what is "chunked"?

Comment: @jwvh Yes that would work. Blocks of text that arrive within a second or each other should be grouped, text will only be input once or twice with significant gaps in between. Can you suggest how to do that idiomatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rough outline, but it seems to work. I had to delve into Java Executors, which I hadn't encountered before, and I might not be using correctly.

You might want to play around with the timeout value, but 10 milliseconds passes my tests.

```
import java.util.concurrent.{Callable, Executors, TimeUnit}
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

def getChunk: List[String] = {  // blocks until StdIn has data
  val executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
  val callable = new Callable[String]() {
    def call(): String = io.StdIn.readLine()
  }

  def nextLine(acc: List[String]): List[String] =
    Try {executor.submit(callable).get(10L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)} match {
      case Success(str) => nextLine(str :: acc)
      case Failure(_)   => executor.shutdownNow() // should test for Failure type
                           acc.reverse
    }

  nextLine(List(io.StdIn.readLine()))  // this is the blocking part
}
```

Usage is quite simple.

```
val input: List[String] = getChunk
```